# Using xlwings to open an Excel file on Mac OS X El Capitan requires Grant Access pop-up

Tags: excel, macos, permissions, xlwings

If I manually grant access to a file, my code is able to open the document in subsequent runs.  I will be working with new files each day so I would like to eliminate the grant access pop up window.   I've tried sudo python myscript.py, but it doesn't resolve the issue.

While the open() function is able to open the file, I want to be able to use the range style referencing available in xlwings.

Will you please tell me how to grant Python (or just my script), not only to the individual files that are currently in the folder but also any files which get added to a folder in the future?

Comment: Will you please tell me what is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 4):

The issue you're seeing has nothing to do with Python or xlwings, but is really a "feature" of Excel 2016 on Mac: It is sandboxed and thus cannot access files outside of the app's directory, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30971616/vb-macros-for-office-2016-for-mac-require-permissions-every-time-they-try-to-acc) and this [tutorial](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac034.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wish you were wrong, but nothing I have been able to find disagrees.  This is deeply disappointing.  The first answer won't help me when there are new files each day, the second looks painful but I'll give it a try.

Comment: I save file here: "~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data" to get around that issue.

Answer (score 3):

To revive this thread for **Office 365** and Catalina: it is still necessary to save Excel files here:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data
```

to avoid the prompt for granting access.

or to this folder generally for Office files:

```
~/Library/Group\ Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office
```